# Calling a function in a class with the class as a parameter in c#

Tags: c#, function, class

```
class Fraction
    {
        public double Num { get; set; }
        public double Denom { get; set; }
        public void show(Fraction f)
        {
            Console.Write($"({f.Num}/{f.Denom})");
        }
     }
```

this bit of code shows no errors, but when I try to actually call the show(Fraction x) function it gives the "The name 'show' does not exist in the current context" error.
I assume I can't set a class as a parameter, then what workaround could you suggest?

Comment: Absolutely no. You can always pass an instance of a class. The problem is in the code that calls the _show_ method. Please add that code.

Comment: then why doesn't it work lol

Comment: remove the `Fraction f` parameter.  An instance method can access the properties directly. `public void show() { Console.Write($"({Num}/{Denom})"); }` and you call it like that: `fraction.show()` (assuming `fraction` is reference variable of type `Fraction`, that you already initialized to an instance of a Fraction with `var fraction = new Fraction();` for instance)

Comment: @Pac0 still the error hints to a different problem.  _"The name 'show' does not exist in the current context"_ removing the parameter will not resolve it

Comment: @Steve of course, `show` by itself is not a top level function, it's an instance method. This error will pop up from any code outside this class. I made some assumptions of course, like that OP is a beginner and their code doesn't contain another `show` function somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution youre looking for

```
class Fraction
    {
        public double Num { get; set; }
        public double Denom { get; set; }
        public void show()
        {
            Console.Write($"({Num}/{Denom})");
        }
     }
```

You would call it this way.

```
var fraction = new Fraction{Num = 10, Denom = 10};
fraction.show();
```